# UITableViewCell height is not changing in UITableView when changing it in Interface Builder

Tags: uitableview, interface-builder

I am making a custom table cell with InterfaceBuilder. However, when I change the height in IB, the changes are not reflected in the running program. Is there anything else I need to do besides set the height in IB?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Changing the height of your custom cell in IB is not enough. The height of a row in a UITableView can be controlled in 2 ways

1. Set the `tableview.rowHeight` property to the desired value if you know all cells will be the same height. You can also set this in IB if i'm not mistaken.
2. Implement the UITableViewDelegate method

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This method takes precedence, meaning that if you implement this method then the value you set in `tableView.rowHeight` is ignored.

Comment: and make sure you have `tableview.delegate = self;` in your code.